# Change default start page on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, navigation

By default stackoverflow.com shows me a page named “Top Questions”, but I would rather see the following:

1. My unanswered questions (to see what’s going on with them)
2. The unanswered questions with my preferred topics (to contribute)

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: we had that a bit in [new nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) but that was disabled but it will return in a similar form in 6 to 8 weeks or so I was told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to change what questions you're shown on the homepage (there used to be a nav which allowed you to do something similar, but that was retired. See [Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/)).

You can see the questions you want easily enough through search though (and bookmark the searches if you like).

To see your unanswered questions search for:

> user:me is:q answers:0

or if you want questions without an *accepted* answer (rather than no answers):

> user:me is:q hasaccepted:no

...

For your favorite tags simply replace the user query with `intags`:

> intags:mine is:q answers:0

or

> intags:mine is:q hasaccepted:no

You can find more advanced search options in [the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks for the intags:mine tip, I was wondering how to do that for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

There was a great beta feature which is no longer there, but it is going to be re-implemented, see: [Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0)

Until then, the only solution you have is a user-script to redirect to the questions list you want.